# django rest framework PUT detail not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When trying to PUT a json file to my api I get the following error -

```
{
    "detail": "Not found"
}
```

This only works if I try to PUT a new item not update and existing one.  Here is my view -

```
class DeployEventView(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Trgmst.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Trgmst.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        name = self.request.GET.get('name')
        pk = Trgmst.objects.filter(trgmst_name=name).values_list('trgmst_id', flat=True)
        trgmst = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = EventSerializer(trgmst)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        name = self.request.GET.get('name')
        pk = Trgmst.objects.filter(trgmst_name=name).values_list('trgmst_id', flat=True)
        trgmst = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = EventSerializer(trgmst, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, format=None):
        name = self.request.GET.get('name')
        pk = Trgmst.objects.filter(trgmst_name=name).values_list('trgmst_id', flat=True)
        trgmst = self.get_object(pk)
        trgmst.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

This is the URL I'm trying to PUT to -

`http://localhost:9001/deploy/event/`

I've also tried this url - (Item doesn't currently exist)

`http://localhost:9001/deploy/event/?name=evnt_job_test`

Here's my json -

```
{
    "trgmst_id": 2249, 
    "trgmst_type": 1, 
    "trgmst_name": "evnt_job_TEST                 ", 
    "trgmst_desc": null, 
    "trgmst_public": "Y", 
    "trgmst_active": "Y", 
    "trgmst_trigger": 10, 
    "owner_name": "Operations                    ", 
    "trgmst_jobctl": 1, 
    "trgmst_alljobs": "N", 
    "trgmst_lstchgtm": "2014-09-26T13:44:27", 
    "trgmst_parm": "OP=0,EX1=1,EX2=1", 
    "trgmst_maxreruns": 0, 
    "nodmst_name": null, 
    "servicemst_name": null, 
    "trgmst_info": null, 
    "trgmst_monitor": 1, 
    "trgmst_trgtskcnt": 0, 
    "trgmst_lasttrgtskrun": null, 
    "event_action_details": [
        {
            "trgtsk_id": 2982, 
            "trgmst_id": 2249, 
            "tskmst_id": null, 
            "trgtsk_order": 1, 
            "trgtsk_type": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Were you able to track down the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely sending the JSON to the browsable API which expects a form, not JSON data.
Try sending the data to the following url:
`http://localhost:9001/deploy/event/?format=json`